# django templates not found

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I have already looked for almost all questions but still none of the answers is working for me. The error I get: [image: Screen Shot]

My BASE_DIRS = "/home/amank/Adevelopment/test/mechanical/templates"
This is okay but still django is looking in different irrelevant paths as shown in screen shot ...

My related settings:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
.
.
.
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Any method to give templates path manually in settings.py?

[Traceback](http://dpaste.com/33PDZN2)

PROBLEM SOLVED ..But still I don't get the reason behind it .I have posted the solution below..

Comment: I edited your last sentence by adding a question mark and deleting the parentheses. I hope I have not misinterpreted what you meant. Can you please check?

Comment: are you staticfiles working? the base dir var should be `BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`, and comment `APP_DIRS` lane

Comment: okay i have figured out the mistake ... my templates are located in project directory  not inside apps of projec ... so its not searching in app (INSTALLED APPS). .. but still is there any way to make django load templates in project..i mean did you get the point .... but i don't understand its working fine on internet( http://www.me.iitb.ac.in/home/ ) why not on my local pc .

Comment: @MauricioCortazar  have tried that too .

Answer (score 0):

Go to your main project directory, make sure you have

```
templates
```

directory inside it. Inside `templates` you should have `home` directory inside which there should be `index.html`

This answer is based on image provided in Question.

Comment: I have it already...i think i shall add my file structure too

Comment: Check your BASE_DIR is `BASE_DIR=os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))`

Answer (score 0):

I got it working somehow but i even don't know how it worked...Basically 
I removed this part fully

```
     TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'debug': DEBUG,
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
]
```

and replaced it with

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    "/home/amank/Adevelopment/test/mechanical/templates",
)
```

It somehow worked .  If anyone can explain why before it wasn't working on PC while same code is running it on internet www.me.iitb.ac.in  ?

Comment: It is not a good way to give absolute path in any `django` project, always prefer to give relative path so that your project work everywhere irrespective of machine, platform and directory in which your root project file is located.